# How to make Team City release the exe once node starts

Tags: node.js, teamcity

I am trying to get a node.js application working on a CI server (Team City). I have a build step which goes like this...

npm start "path/to/my/app"

And it works however the build step hangs because the console will not shut down (it can't because it needs to stay open to run the server). So what can I do to get Team City to kick off the command line without staying open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing a more general problem of running node.js as a background service (the one that does not hold the console etc.)

Common solution to this is to use [Forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) CLI tool